# JQuery DatePicker style issue

Tags: internet-explorer, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm currently learning how to use the jquery datepicker in my asp pages so that I can implement calendars. I am able to get the calendar to display for my 3 browsers (Firefox, IE9, and Chrome) but for some reason the style of the calendar is off on my IE browser. The month and year dropdown list are on top of each other instead of side-by-side and the prev arrow is over the month dropdown list instead of being on the left side of the calendar. My question is why is it displaying weird in IE9 and how can I fix it so that it would look the same across all browsers?

Here are the two images of how it looks in Chrome/Firefox and in IE:

Chrome/Firefox Calendar:

[image: Chrome/Firefox Calendar]

IE9 Calendar:

[image: IE9 Calendar]

Here is the piece of code that I used to handle the click and display of the calendar:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">  
<script src="/javascript/jquerydatepicker/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>  
<script src="/javascript/jquerydatepicker/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">

var strDate;

$(function ()
{
    $("#Date1").datepicker(
    {
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true
    });

    $("#img_Date1").click(function ()
    {
        $("#Date1").datepicker("show");
    });

    $("#Date1").datepicker("setDate", strDate);
});

if (strDate == '')
{
    var dtTempDate = new Date();
    dtTempDate.setMonth(dtTempDate.getMonth() - 2);
    document.getElementById("Date1").value = (dtTempDate.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + dtTempDate.getDate() + '/' + (dtTempDate.getFullYear());
}

document.getElementById("Date1").value = strDate;

...irrelevant code
</script>
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with the `jquery_ui.css` but I have not used css files before so I wouldn't know where to begin to look for the styles. Here is the html code for the header part of the calendar that was created when the calendar displays:

```
<DIV class="ui-datepicker-header ui-widget-header ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all">
    <A class="ui-datepicker-prev ui-corner-all" title=Prev data-event="click" data-handler="prev">
        <SPAN class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-w">Prev</SPAN>
    </A>
    <A class="ui-datepicker-next ui-corner-all" title=Next data-event="click" data-handler="next">
        <SPAN class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-e">Next</SPAN>
    </A>
    <DIV class=ui-datepicker-title>
        <SELECT class=ui-datepicker-month data-event="change" data-handler="selectMonth">
            <OPTION value=0>Jan</OPTION>
            ...
            <OPTION selected value=10>Nov</OPTION>
            <OPTION value=11>Dec</OPTION>
        </SELECT>
        <SELECT class=ui-datepicker-year data-event="change" data-handler="selectYear">
            <OPTION value=2004>2004</OPTION>
            ...
            <OPTION selected value=2014>2014</OPTION>
            ...
            <OPTION value=2024>2024</OPTION>
        </SELECT>
    </DIV>
</DIV>
```

I have also tried updating JQuery to the latest version (1.11.2) with the following script/link tags but still get the same result:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/javascript/jquerydatepicker/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/javascript/jquerydatepicker/jquery-ui.structure.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/javascript/jquerydatepicker/jquery-ui.theme.css">
<script src="/javascript/jquerydatepicker/external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>  
<script src="/javascript/jquerydatepicker/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the datepicker html elements was inheriting a `text-align: center` css style from the body element from another css file that I included. That `text-align` style caused the prev arrow in the calendar to not be on the left side of the calendar like it was suppose to be.

To fix the inheritance issue without modifying the other css file, since it is being used across multiple asp files, I added the `text-align: justify` style to the `.ui-datepicker` style to cancel it out.

To fix the dropdown lists not being side-by-side I changed the width in the `.ui-date picker select.ui-datepicker-month` and `.ui-datepicker select.ui-datepicker-year` style to 40% instead of 45%.

With those fixes the prev arrow is now properly set to the left side of the calendar and the month/year dropdown lists are side-by-side.

Answer (score 0):

you must add this code block

```
<!--[if IE 5]>
<style> 
    .ui-datepicker SELECT.ui-datepicker-month{
        width:40%;
    }
    .ui-datepicker SELECT.ui-datepicker-year{
        width:30%;
    }
</style>
<![endif]-->
```